# php ftp_connect over explicit connection with no authentication

Tags: php

I've moved over a website from one server to another that contains the following function:

```
public function ftpConnect() {

            $this->ftpHost = $this->getVar('ftp','host');
            $this->ftpUsername = $this->getVar('ftp','username');
            $this->ftpPassword = $this->getVar('ftp','password');

            $this->ftpStream = @ftp_connect($this->ftpHost);
            $ftpLogin = @ftp_login($this->ftpStream, $this->ftpUsername, trim($this->ftpPassword));

            $rootList = ftp_nlist($this->ftpStream, '.');
            if (in_array('public_html', $rootList)) {
                ftp_chdir($this->ftpStream, 'public_html/');    
            }

            $this->createDirs();
        }
```

But the new server must connect ftp with SSL/TLS with explicit encryption and no authentication.

I tried changing the `@ftp_connect` to `@ftp_ssl_connect` but it still doesn't want to know, is there something else I'm not doing?

Or is that all that's needed and the ftp details it's using simply aren't correct?

Any help is eternally grateful.

Comment: have you tried `ftp_ssl_connect()` ?? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-ssl-connect.php

Comment: Yes I have, that's exactly what I'm trying to say (not very well I'll admit)

Comment: ohh ok.. have you tried turning on/off the passive mode?? it can be done using `ftp_pasv($connection,TRUE/FALSE)`..  http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the ftp details didn't copy over correctly. I reset the ftp password, changed the `@ftp_connect` to `@ftp_ssl_connect` and all the errors went away. I've left the question up just in case anyone else wants to know how to connect to ftp explicit through php.